# HDMI audio not working but option always listed, even without cable

Tags: sound, hdmi

Today my laptop decided to not use the HDMI audio output (video is OK). Strange thing is thatthe hdmi audio option is always listed, even without inserting the cable.

[image: the hdmi audio option is always listed],

The problem occured on Ubuntu 20.04 and I tried switching to 20.10 as suggested on another topic, without changes.